# VS2015 (Windows 10 UWP) Adds instance refrence to a static field and then complains

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

Visual Studio does this and complains:

[image: Visual Studio does this and complains]

I can fix it just fine, but it eventually switches it back and complains again:

[image: I can fix it just fine, but it eventually switches it back and complains again]

What is going on? Is there any way to fix this?

Links to code (I had to take off the http because I can only post 2 links)

LocationsPage.xaml: pastebin.com/SBxxKs7J
LocationsPage.xaml.cs: pastebin.com/gk1QfD0z
Yes I realize that my code is the most spaghetti that you have seen in your entire life :P

Also note, I need to be able to access Locations (line 33 of .cs) from other classes, so it needs to be static. I think that I *could* make it in a different way, but it would require a lot of work that I would like to avoid.

Comment: thanks for adding in my images GSerg

Comment: What's wrong on the second screenshot?

Comment: Nothing I was showing that I can fix it.

Comment: And then it magically changes back to the first screenshot?

Comment: yes in fact it did it just now

Comment: not right away but it eventually happens

Comment: its not just this file either. I switched a variable in a different class to static and it did the same thing.

Comment: Thats a generated file you shouldnt be changing that. Do a clean then rebuild or failing that look at your static class/method theres something wrong there

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem is in the LocationsPage.g.cs file, this file is generated by your LocationsPage.xaml file. You can't edit the code inside, even you edit it, it will eventually go back to the old code.

So you problem is actually with your LocationsPage.xaml file, and you should correct the problem in this file, or maybe also the code behind in the LocationsPage.xaml.cs file.

And your problem is:

> Member `LocationsPage.Locations` cannot be accessed with an instance reference;

I think you have a Class named "LocationsPage" and there is a member inside this class named "Locations", and this "Locations" is a static member, static members belong to the class itself and not to an instance of that class.

To solve this problem, you can try to remove the `static` from your "Locations", or you can post the code of your LocationsPage.xaml and LocationsPage.xaml.cs, so can we take a investigation to this case.

Comment: @MrabEzreb, I just tested your code, is there any problem if you remove the static from `ObservableCollection<Location> Locations` and your `Locs_Loaded_S()` method?

Comment: yes, because that variable and method need to be accessable from other pages.

Comment: @MrabEzreb, there is problem when you use x:Bind with a static field, please remove this, and in your code replace the `Locs.DataContext = Locations;` with `Locs.ItemsSource = Locations;`, in a word, you can directly give this collection to the itemsource in the code behind.